# Преобразование строки в HWND на C++

Tags: c++

У меня есть строка с 16-ричным числом (например 0xb0844):

```
String h;
```

И переменная типа HWND:

```
HWND h1;
```

Вопрос: как мне конвертировать строку в хэндл HWND?

Далее использую

```
SetForegroundWindow(h1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот так например:

```
if(1 != ::std::sscanf(text.c_str(), "0x%zx", ::std::addressof(handle)))
{
    throw ::std::runtime_error{"bad value"};
}
```